# click event problem in button when click on span tag and img tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
Searchable Dropdown

  /* Styles for dropdown */
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #dropdownButton {
    background-color: white;
    width: 350px;
    height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 0 10px;
  }

  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 320px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 200px;
  }

  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 6px 0;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  #dropdownInput {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .show {
    display: block;
  }
  #myDropdown {
    display: none;
  }
</style>




  
    Select Subject Name
    <img src="arrowdown.png" />
  

  <div
    class="dropdown-content"
    id="myDropdown"
    onclick="preventClose(event)"
  >
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search.."
      id="dropdownInput"
      oninput="filterFunction()"
    />
    <a href="#" onclick="selectOption(this)">Option 1</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="selectOption(this)">Option 2</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="selectOption(this)">Option 3</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="selectOption(this)">Option 4</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="selectOption(this)">Option 5</a>
    <!-- Add more options as needed -->
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  // Function to toggle dropdown visibility
  function toggleDropdown(event) {
    var dropdownii = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    // console.log(dropdown);
    if (dropdownii.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownii.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownii.style.display = "block";
    }

    let target = event.target;
    if (target.tagName === "SPAN" || target.tagName === "IMG") {
      console.log("inside event ...");
      if (dropdownii.style.display === "block") {
        console.log("inside this block scope");
        dropdownii.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        console.log("inside this none scope");
        dropdownii.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
    console.log("click occurs");
  }

  // Function to close dropdown when click outside
  window.onclick = function (event) {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    var input = document.getElementById("dropdownInput");
    var button = document.getElementById("dropdownButton"); // Added button reference
    if (
      event.target != dropdown &&
      event.target != input &&
      event.target != button // Added button condition
    ) {
      dropdown.style.display = "none";
    }
  };

  function preventClose(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }

  // Function to filter options based on input
  function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("dropdownInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        a[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        a[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }

  // Function to select option and display its value
  function selectOption(option) {
    var selectedValue = option.textContent;
    document.getElementById("selectedValue").textContent = selectedValue;
    toggleDropdown(); // Close dropdown after selecting an option
  }
</script>
```

this is my code which displays searchable dropdown on click but that click event doesn't work for span tag and img tag inside button can anyone explain why this is happening and what should i do for it

when i click on button anywhere dropdown should be display
i have mention my css html and javascript code

Comment: Your HTML seems to be missing some tags. Are you sure you posted your code correctly? The reason I'm asking - there seems to be a stray `</div>`  right before your first `<script>`. Also, your `selectOption` function is querying the DOM for `#selectedValue` which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen your code. It seems like The issue you're encountering with your dropdown not toggling when clicking on the  or  tags inside the button is likely due to how the event listeners are set up. Currently, your event listener is attached to the entire window to close the dropdown when clicking outside of it, and the toggle function is directly tied to the button click. However, when you click on the  or  tags, they are not the direct targets of the event, so the toggle function doesn't get called.

To fix this, you can modify your event handling logic to ensure that clicking on the  or  tags inside the button triggers the toggle function. You can achieve this by adding event listeners directly to those elements as well.

```mixed
<div class="dropdown" onclick="toggleDropdown(event)">
  <button id="dropdownButton">
    <span>Select Subject Name</span>
    <img src="arrowdown.png" />
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown" onclick="preventClose(event)">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="dropdownInput" oninput="filterFunction()" />
    <a href="#" onclick="selectOption(this)">Option 1</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="selectOption(this)">Option 2</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="selectOption(this)">Option 3</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="selectOption(this)">Option 4</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="selectOption(this)">Option 5</a>
    <!-- Add more options as needed -->
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  // Function to toggle dropdown visibility
  function toggleDropdown(event) {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (dropdown.style.display === "block") {
      dropdown.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdown.style.display = "block";
    }
    event.stopPropagation(); // Prevent the event from bubbling up to the window
  }

  // Event listener for button clicks
  document.getElementById("dropdownButton").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    toggleDropdown(event);
  });

  // Event listener for span clicks
  document.querySelector("#dropdownButton span").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    toggleDropdown(event);
  });

  // Event listener for img clicks
  document.querySelector("#dropdownButton img").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    toggleDropdown(event);
  });

  // Function to close dropdown when click outside
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    var input = document.getElementById("dropdownInput");
    if (event.target != dropdown && event.target != input) {
      dropdown.style.display = "none";
    }
  };

  function preventClose(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }

  // Function to filter options based on input
  function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, div, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("dropdownInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        a[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        a[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }

  // Function to select option and display its value
  function selectOption(option) {
    var selectedValue = option.textContent;
    document.getElementById("selectedValue").textContent = selectedValue;
    toggleDropdown(); // Close dropdown after selecting an option
  }
</script>
```

Comment: it works but when i select any option from dropdown i get this error on console
 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stopPropagation')
    at toggleDropdown (index.html:90:15)
    at selectOption (index.html:148:9)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM66 index.html:1:1)